# PDFBox - Accessible PDF - How to check if PDF Tags have properties as per Accessiblity guidelines

Tags: java, pdf, accessibility, pdfbox

Need to check if PDF Tags have properties as per Accessibility guidelines.
Examples:

- H1 - validate that a H1 exists in the PDF
- Image(Figure Tag) - validate image\figure has a Alt text
- Language - Validate that language property is set so that screen reader will read properly. For Spanish and English documents, respective Language codes should be updated
- Tables - access table object and validate that table structure is proper (headers columns match with row column etc)

So far I was able to:

- Extract the Metadata and validate the document has proper Title, Subject and Producer info by `PDDocument.getDocumentInformation().getMetadataKeys();`
- Validate if PDF is accessible or not by checking `PDDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getMarkInfo().isMarked();` flag

To access the Tags, I have tried these options:

- `getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm()` returns Null
- `PDDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0).getAnnotations();` returns Null
- I tried looping through `PDDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getStructureTreeRoot().getKids()` but its returning only 1 `StructElem` type object

Creation of Accessible PDF is done using OpenText so Dev team doesn't know about PDFBox. 
I am lost here as how to get the access to Tags/Objects (use MarkedContent or something else).

Please suggest how to extract the individual objects(tags) such as P, H1, Table, Figure/Image and validate their properties.
Note: Manual validation of these properties are performed using Adobe Acrobat Pro

Comment: Please share a PDF that has these tags and ping me. What you are searching is in the structure tree, also look at it with PDFDebugger.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you for the response. Unfortunately I cannot share the PDF which I have to validate. Here are the sample PDFs. In the below PDF, I need to validate that Fox and dog images have proper alt texts. 
http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/raw/develop/publications/jumpstart/cmpfiles/chapter07/cmp_quick_brown_fox_PDFA-1a.pdf

In the below PDF, I need to validate that Table structure is right. Like it has TH, TBody tags. Each TD is mapped.
http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/raw/develop/publications/jumpstart/cmpfiles/chapter07/cmp_united_states_PDFA-3a.pdf

Comment: I had a look… this is more tricky than I thought, sorry. If you'll look at it with PDFDebugger you'll see why :-(

Comment: No problem, Thank you for checking. I haven't used PDFDebugger before, will check.

Comment: @SachinG Have you got any lead on this? Also, `PDDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getStructureTreeRoot().getKids() but its returning only 1 StructElem type object` Did you find a way to iterate this `StrucElem`.

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya - I was unable to proceed much further on it, so ditched the project and moved on for other priority tasks.

Comment: @SachinG I feel you! I am working on it now.

Answer (score 3):

Based upon https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-7, it appears that you can use PDFMarkedContentExtractor to get the information that you need.